# XML schema: Venetian Blind Design and pretty list types

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I'm trying to create a XML schema for the following document. I want a `List` element that can either contain `TextItem`s or `List`s:

```
<!-- a "List" containing "TextItem"s: -->

<List>
  <TextItem><TextItemData>foo</TextItemData></TextItem>
  <TextItem><TextItemData>bar</TextItemData></TextItem>
</List>


<!-- a "List" containing "List"s of "TextItem"s: -->

<List>

  <List>
    <TextItem><TextItemData>foo1</TextItemData></TextItem>
    <TextItem><TextItemData>bar1</TextItemData></TextItem>
  </List>

  <List>
    <TextItem><TextItemData>foo2</TextItemData></TextItem>
    <TextItem><TextItemData>bar2</TextItemData></TextItem>
  </List>

</List>
```

The following XML schema definition accomplishes the task:

```
<xs:complexType name="TextItemType">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="TextItemData" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="ListType">
  <xs:choice>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="TextItem"    type="TextItemType"    minOccurs="0"   maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="List"          type="ListType"        minOccurs="0"   maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

What I actually want is lists such as the following (without the `TextItemData`):

```
<List>
  <TextItem>foo</TextItem>
  <TextItem>bar</TextItem>
</List>
```

I could incorporate the definition of `TextItem` into the definition of `List` to get rid of the `TextItemData`. However, the definition of `TextItem` is in fact rather complicated due to attributes that I ommitted in the example. Furthermore, there are also other kinds of items, such as `BinaryItems`. The definition of `List` would grow unreadably large.

How do I remove the need for the `TextItemData` element?

Comment: Have you tried putting `<xs:element ref="TextItem" minOccurs="0"   maxOccurs="unbounded"/>` in the `ListType` definition?

Comment: @JLRishe: I tried and it worked (after I created a `TextItem` element). However, `TextItem` still contains the unwanted `TextItemData`.

Comment: Could you show us the actual definitions of `TextItem` and `TextItemType` rather than alluding to them?

Comment: @JLRishe: It's in my post, sub-element of `ListType`. The new definition (needed for `ref`) is this: `<xs:element name="TextItem" type="TextItemType"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you're actually trying to do is this:

```
  <xs:complexType name="TextItemType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute name="FirstAttribute" />
        <xs:attribute name="SecondAttribute" />
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="TextItem" type="TextItemType" />
```

But defining TextItemType is unnecessary if you're only going to use it for that one element. You could do this instead:

```
  <xs:element name="TextItem">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
          <xs:attribute name="FirstAttribute" />
          <xs:attribute name="SecondAttribute" />
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```